# Why is it better to to process the input array from right to left in Distribution-Counting sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Here's the algorithm

[image: Algorithm]

The author says

> "It is more convenient to process the input array right to left."

How is it any different than reading the array from 0 to n-1?

Comment: There is a difference between "better" and "more convenient." You should try modifying his code to process from left to right. Sometimes counting backwards is more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which the input array is processed in the last step doesn't matter. The author is wrong.

It is more convenient to fill the "bins" in the output array from right to left, though. It's also possible to fill them from left to right, increasing the indices in `D` instead of decreasing them, but this makes third step where the cumulative frequencies are calculated a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

For left to right, a simple option is to make D[] one element larger. The size of D[] = u + 2 - l. The last entry is not used for distribution, but it saves using a check to skip cases of A[] == u or using two local variables. The end goal is D[0] = 0, D[1] = # instances of u, D[2] = # instances of u + # instances of u+1, ...

```
    for j ← 0 to u+1-l do D[j] = 0                     // reset counts
    for i ← 0 to n-1   do D[A[i]+1-l] = D[A[i]+1-l]+1  // set   counts
    for j ← 2 to u-l   do D[j] ← D[j-1] + D[j]         // convert to indicies
    for i ← 0 to n-1 do                                // distribute
        j ← A[i] - l
        S[D[j]] ← A[i]
        D[j] ← D[j] + 1
    return S
```

Using two local variables instead:

```
    for j ← 0 to u+l do D[j] = 0                       // reset counts
    for i ← 0 to n-1 do D[A[i]-l] = D[A[i]-l]+1        // set   counts
    k = 0                                              // k == sum
    for j ← 0 to u-l do                                // convert to indicies
        i ← D[j]
        D[j] ← k
        k ← k + i
    for i ← 0 to n-1 do                                // distribute
        j ← A[i] - l
        S[D[j]] ← A[i]
        D[j] ← D[j] + 1
    return S
```

Instead of distribution, it could just be a counting sort:

```
    for j ← 0 to u-l do C[j] = 0                       // reset counts
    for i ← 0 to n-1 do C[A[i]-l] = C[A[i]-l]+1        // set   counts
    i = 0                                              // generate sorted array
    for j ← 0 to u-l do
        while(C[j] != 0) do
            S[i] ← j-l
            i ← i+1
            C[j] ← C[j]-1
    return S
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any differences. Indeed, no matter what order of elements `A` has, result is the same.

Maybe, author implied some specific implementation. E.g. in C++ `for(size_t i = n; i--; )` is shorter and more convenient for someone.